# Cutting a cube and a torus

Tags: mathematics, geometry, visual

How should you cut a cube with a single planar cut so that one face is

- a regular hexagon?
- a regular octagon?

How should you cut a torus with a single planar cut so that you get

- two same-radius circles with different centres?
- three circles?
- ovals, like the circles?

Comment: You deleted your [previous puzzle](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42881/hit-hiss-the-purse-hit-murder-go-test)? :-(

Comment: @randal'thor Yes, it contained no trace of soul uplifting beauty, but very ugly and clunky.

Comment: @tpk Awesome reason to delete a question. I wonder what happened of everyone here did that.

Comment: I agree, but I don't think that puzzle actually merited deletion.

Answer (score 4):

### Cube

Hexagon:

[image: cube]

Octagon:

> **impossible**, because a cube only has 6 faces and so we can only form polygons with at most 6 sides by taking single planar cuts through a cube.

### Torus

Concentric circles:

[image: torus]

Non-equal same-radius circles:

[image: torus]

<sub>(I already knew how to do this, but for ease of answering I sourced the images from [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hexagon.html) and [here](http://paulbourke.net/fun/toruscut/).)</sub>

Comment: Oh I miswrrote the question. See it again.

Comment: What bout the Other ones ?

Comment: @tpk Are you sure an octagon and three circles are possible?

Comment: Hint - why the mathematics tag ? Visual tag would suffice.

Comment: @humn Oops. What I really meant was non-equal. I really should be in bed by now.

Answer (score 2):

#### Two circles

> A plane through the centre of the torus, perpendicular to the hole.

#### Two ellipses

> Same, but **not** through the centre.